# printing fibonacci numbers in tens line by line

Tags: java

i wrote a program to display fibonacci series in java but now i want the numbers in the sequence to be displayed in tens that is the first ten fibonacci numbers on one line followed by the next ten on the next line and so.....
i have been having real problems making that possible.

this is the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Fibonacci {

public static void main(String args[]) {


    System.out.print("Enter number upto which Fibonacci series to print: ");
    int number = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

    System.out.println("\n\nFibonacci series upto " + number + " numbers : ");

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {

        System.out.println(fibonacciLoop(i) + " ");
    }
}

public static BigInteger fibonacciLoop(int number) {
    if (number == 1 || number == 2) {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    }
    for (int x = 1; x <= number; x++){
        return BigInteger.valueOf(x);
    }
    BigInteger fibonacci = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    BigInteger fibo1 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    BigInteger fibo2 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    for (int i = 3; i <= number; i++) {
        fibonacci = fibo1.add(fibo2);
        fibo1 = fibo2;
        fibo2 = fibonacci;
    }
    return fibonacci;
}
}
```

Comment: BigInteger.valueOf(1) = BigInteger.ONE;

Comment: The first loop in your fibonacciLoop is broken. It will return 3 for every value after the first 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your fibonaci calculation does not work due to the following for loop:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= number; x++){
        return BigInteger.valueOf(x);
    }
```

The follow will do what you requested:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class Test {

    Test(int number) {
        System.out.println("\n\nFibonacci series upto " + number + " numbers : ");
        LinkedList<BigInteger> list = new LinkedList<BigInteger>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            list.add(fibonacciLoop(i));
            if(list.size() == 10) {
                printFibo(list);
                list = new LinkedList<BigInteger>();
            }
        }
        if(!list.isEmpty()) printFibo(list);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("Enter number upto which Fibonacci series to print: ");
        new Test(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
    }

    private void printFibo(LinkedList<BigInteger> list) {
        for(BigInteger fiboNumber : list) {
             System.out.print(fiboNumber + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public BigInteger fibonacciLoop(int number) {
        if (number == 1 || number == 2) {
            return BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        }
        BigInteger fibonacci = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        BigInteger fibo1 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        BigInteger fibo2 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        for (int i = 3; i <= number; i++) {
            fibonacci = fibo1.add(fibo2);
            fibo1 = fibo2;
            fibo2 = fibonacci;
        }
        return fibonacci;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`print` (don't `println`) each number to have them on the same line. And whenever your counter `i` is a multiple of 10, start a new line.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    System.out.print(fibonacciLoop(i) + " ");
    if (i % 10 == 0)
        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt realize that, am pretty new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(i % 10 == 0)
{
    System.out.println();
}
```

Or if you wanted to be fancy.

```
System.out.print(fibonacciLoop(i) + " " + (i % 10 == 0? "\n":""));
```

Comment: Fancyness should be avoided if it makes your code basically unreadable, especially for programmers without years of experience.

Comment: @DennisTraub I know, but given my answer had already really been provided, I thought I'd add something new, just for future readers. And while fancyness is discouraged, it's good to know it, for when someone uses it.